# How to add an element to PHP array without deleting element that is already in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add an element to PHP array when form is submitted and then add that array to `$_SESSION` so I can display it on other page while `$_SESSION` is active, but when an element is added to an array, element that is already in it is deleted so I constantly have 1 item in array. Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
$korpa = array();
$_SESSION["korpa"] = $korpa;

if(isset($_POST["add"])){
    array_push($korpa, $_POST["id"]);
}
```

Comment: Well you're pushing to `$korpa` which is defined as an empty array at the beginning of your code, so you end up with exactly one item in it. Why would you expect otherwise? Also note that `$korpa[] = $_POST['id'];` would be a more common way to write that (and also a bit faster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep assigning an empty array to your session variable, so it will be empty at the start of your script, before you append the POST variable.

Instead, you can append directly to that session variable if the condition is met.

```
// Initialize the session array if its not set
if (!isset($_SESSION["korpa"])) {
    $_SESSION["korpa"] = [];
}

// Then append the POST value to the session if that's set
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
    $_SESSION["korpa"][] = $_POST["add"];
}
```

Naturally you will need to call `session_start()` at the top of every page using sessions, otherwise they will not be set across your different pages.